# Disable a JS function while another function is running

Tags: javascript, function, conditional-statements

What I'm trying to do seems so simple but I can't figure it out.

Here's the basic scenario:

- Function A is running
- Function B starts when a button is clicked
- I need to disable Function A while Function B is running
- Then when Function B is complete, re enable Function A (back to where we started).

I have setup a very basic Pen to help illustrate what I'm trying to achieve. You can ignore the fact that the functions add classes, this was just to have it do something.

https://codepen.io/andystent/pen/yLNbyjZ?editors=1111

So in the example the desired scenario would be:

- Block is green
- Block changes to red when button is clicked
- After changing to red, block changes back to green

*Again, ignore the color changes and adding/removing classes - that is just to have something happen.*

**JS from the Pen example:**

```
var block = document.getElementById("block");
var button = document.getElementById("button");

//Function A: the main function that is active by default - I need this function disabled/stopped when the button is clicked, and then re enabled when Function B is complete.
$(document).ready(function(){
  block.classList.add("green"); //adding class is only for example
});

//Function B
$(button).click(function(){
  block.classList.add("red"); //adding class is only for example
});
```

**UPDATE 1**

This is my working based on answers from Jasper and Adder.

Using the separate functions works great but when I click the button the console.log works but I can still do what's happening in the if statement, as if active = true.

In this example, when I click the button it should change active to "false" and therefore not allow the if statement's content to work. I hope that makes sense....

```
    var aActive = true;


    // FUNCTION A - Active is True
    function fA(){
      aActive = true;
      console.log("active = true");
    };

    //FUNCTION B - Active is False
    function fB(){
      aActive = false;
      console.log("active = false");
    }

    //When clicking Nav link run Function B (active false)
    var navLinks2 = document.querySelectorAll("#nav-wrap nav a")

    navLinks2.forEach(function (navLink2) {
      navLink2.addEventListener('click', function () {
        fB();
        //fA();
      });
    });



    //Only do this if Active is TRUE
    if(aActive) {

      //do something

    } //end if active
```

Comment: I updated my answer with a code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a variable to control function A. This technique can be useful when trying to avoid endless recursion by change triggers.

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");

var aActive = true;

//Function A: the main function that is active by default - I need this function disabled/stopped when the button is clicked, and then re enabled when Function B is complete.
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(aActive) {
        block.classList.add("green"); //adding class is only for example
    }
});

//Function B
$(button).click(function(){
  aActive = false;
  block.classList.add("red"); //adding class is only for example
  aActive = true;
});
```

I think you want something different though:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var block = document.getElementById("block");

var aActive = true;

//Function fA: the main function that is active by default - I need this function disabled/stopped when the button is clicked, and then re enabled when Function B is complete.
function fA(){
 if(aActive) {
  block.classList.add("green"); //adding class is only for example
  block.classList.remove("red");
 }
}

function fB(){
  aActive = false;
  block.classList.add("red"); //adding class is only for example
  block.classList.remove("green");
  aActive = true;
}

$(document).ready(fA);

//Function B
$(button).click(function() {
 setTimeout(fB,0);
 setTimeout(fA,3000);
});
```

```css
.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Click me</button>
<div id="block">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: this could be what I'm looking for! Sort of a combo of Jasper's answer, with the functions outside the callback, and adding the variable. I'm going to give this a go in the actual project and see if it works. I'll post the original code if I get stuck. Thank you both!

Comment: I have updated my question based on your advice. I feel I'm really close but can't quite get it right. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @KablooeyMonster I feel I need to address a misunderstanding: You cannot disable a function's effect by putting it in `if`. What you can do is to stop it from *running* its code when the function is called.

Comment: Thank you Adder, I'm pretty new to JS so thank you for your patience. Let me explain what I'm actually trying to achieve in my project.

I have a smooth scrolling effect on my site based on the mouse wheel scrolling. I also have # anchor links in the navigation. Currently when you click the anchor links they sometime get stuck because of the smooth scrolling script.

Basically I want the smooth scrolling script to be ignored when an anchor link is clicked. Does this make more sense? 

Again, thank you for your help so far! I'm really learning a lot!

Comment: @KablooeyMonster The code in this answer shows how to disable function `fA` when running `fB`. Try to understand it and copy it more accurately into your code. Because your edits in the question are not complete. `fA` would be your smooth scrolling script and `fB` your anchor link clicked script. `fA` is disabled by placing the function body in an `if(aActive)` and setting `aActive` to `false` in `fB` and also setting `aActive` to `true` at the end of `fB`. You might have to use a timeout there.

Comment: Thank you @Adder, this was very helpful and I have managed to get it working exactly as needed. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be confused about how the `.ready()` method works.
 As with all functions in JavaScript, as soon as they finish executing they are removed from the call stack.

This function is actually only called once (when the full DOM is available and loaded in).

I think the best option would probably create functions outside of the callback, that can be reused in each event

e.g

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");

function addGreenClass() {
    block.classList.add("green"); // Obviously putting the correct things in each function
};

function addRedClass() {
    block.classList.add("red"); // Obviously putting the correct things in each function
};

$(document).ready(addGreenClass);
$(button).click(function() {
    addRedClass();
    addGreenClass();
});
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you @Jasper . This could definitely point me in the right direction!

Comment: I have updated my question based on your advice. It's a combo of your idea to keep the functions separate, and @Adder 's idea to use an action variable. Do you have any advice on how my new edit could work? Thank you for your help!